copy activity - copy files and different folders from one container to another container synapse pipeline
I have a container which inside has multiple files,subfolders and sub zip folders which have different files inside the folders like csv, xlsx . I wanted to copy all the files and folders from this container to other container.

I have used the copy activity which is suggested in this thread How to copy all files and folders in specific directory using azure data factory but it fails with the below error.

I have tried concurrency as 1 but no luck is there any other way where I can copy all the files and folders from this container to other?

You can follow the below approach to get the expected output:
Below is the input from a storage container:

The pipeline consist of Get Metadata   activity to retrieve all the filles from input container.
select  the Child items in the field list

Use get metadata activity  childItems as Items in foreach acitivity
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems

Inside for each activity, create two copy activities, one for the
get all the folders and other activity to retrieve all the files. Inside copy activity you need to select Wildcard path to get the folders as shown the below:

Add another copy activity to copy the files with dataset parameter filename for file name with value @item().name as shown below:

After successful of debug pipeline folders and files copied to another container as shown below:

Here is the pipeline Json for your reference:
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Binary1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy data1_copy1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                        "quoteAllText": true,
                                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "src1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sink1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1_copy1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "BinarySource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "wildcardFolderPath": "*",
                                        "wildcardFileName": "*",
                                        "deleteFilesAfterCompletion": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "BinarySink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Binary1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Binary2",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}

